# How to we get list of Installed packages and it version number

Tags: soql, package-install

Is there a way to get version number using SOQL, The below once retrieves only NamespacePrefix, how do i get current version installed..?

```
SELECT AllowedLicenses,CreatedDate,ExpirationDate,Id,IsProvisioned,LastModifiedDate,NamespacePrefix,Status,SystemModstamp,UsedLicenses FROM PackageLicense
```

Comment: You can't do this in SOQL. There are ways to get this data, but we need to know what you're trying to do, since the solution would depend on your intent.

Comment: I'm using jsforce plugin on nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on the jsForce response. This can also be done via the tooling API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_installedsubscriberpackage.htm

```
conn.tooling.sobject('InstalledSubscriberPackage').find({ },[
  "SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix",
  "SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion",
  "SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion",
  "SubscriberPackageVersion.PatchVersion"
])
.execute((err, records) =>{
  if (err) { console.error(err); }
  records.forEach((el) =>{
    console.log(
      el.SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix
      + " v" +
      el.SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion
      + "." +
      el.SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion
      + "." +
      el.SubscriberPackageVersion.PatchVersion
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to some answers, you can use SOQL to retrieve this information. You just can't use it in Apex.

In the developer console, if you check the "Use Tooling API" option, the following query will return the information you want:

```
SELECT Id, SubscriberPackageId, SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix,
    SubscriberPackage.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.Id,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.PatchVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.BuildNumber
FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage
ORDER BY SubscriberPackageId
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Salesforce CLI (sfdx)](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) makes it very easy to get a list of installed packages and their version ids:

`sfdx force:package:installed:list`

Output:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": [
    {
      "Id": "0A33A000000QgeWSAS",
      "SubscriberPackageId": "0331C00000083VFQAY",
      "SubscriberPackageName": "lwc-json-view",
      "SubscriberPackageNamespace": null,
      "SubscriberPackageVersionId": "04t1C000000goKJQAY",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionName": "ver 0.2",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionNumber": "0.2.0.1"
    }, //... other packages
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not doable via sOQL. Using JSForce, you can do a `Metadata Retrieve` requesting the following members

`conn.metadata.retrieve({
    apiVersion: '39.0',
    singlePackage: true,
    unpackaged: {
      types: [{
        'members': ['*'],
        'name': 'InstalledPackage'
      }]
    }
  })`

The response would return all installed packages and and an attribute for their `versionNumber`

Comment: Note that this returns multiple instances of the same InstalledPackage if it has been installed multiple times with different versions